# Unable to accessing Google app engine dev server from other computers

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-eclipse-plugin

I successfully set up a GAE dev server on my computer using Eclipse which is now accessible at :8889. But this server is only accessible from my computer. I can't access it from my android phone's browser and other computer (which is connected to the same network). The browser would give "could not connect" error on trying.

I tried netstat -an and found

```
Local Address        Foreign Address    State
<myIP>:8889          0.0.0.0            Listening
```

I gathered through searching through internet that this is how it should be if you want other computers to access your server. But still other computers can't access my server.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

To access your GAE dev server from other computers in your network, you will need to start the Dev Server with the following arguments. `--address=0.0.0.0`. This will enable it for access from other machines.

Please refer to the docs for other arguments: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Command_Line_Arguments

Comment: Can you tell me what version of App Engine SDK you are using ?

Comment: 1.8.9.
Is it like other computers can access my server only after I deploy it on Google cloud?

Comment: No. It is not necessary that you need to deploy to the Google Cloud. Ofcourse if you deploy to the cloud, you can access it from anywhere but lets not worry about that for the moment. Can you do the following: try --host=0.0.0.0 instead of --address=0.0.0.0 and see if that works ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in Eclipse.  Right click on project name -> Debug As (or Run As) -> Configurations... -> Arguments.  In the Program arguments area replace

```
--port=8889
```

with

```
--port=8889 --address=0.0.0.0
```

then Debug or Run.  Also check port availability and software firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using python appengine 1.9.14. In that version --address is replaced with

```
--host=0.0.0.0
```

I don't know when the change was made.